# Using function with jQuery in GTM (Custom HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-tag-manager

I've tested this function and its call in the console and it works great. But, I'm using it in GTM within a custom HTML tag and no go. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

```
<script>
  
function myFunction(a,b,c,d,f) {

jQuery(document).on(a, b, function(e) {
        dataLayer.push({
            "event" : 'event',
            "event_category": c,
            "event_action": d,
            "event_label": f
        });
});

}

myFunction('mousedown','#top_nav_link_331','test1','test2','test3');

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  (function() {

    function myFunction(a, b, c, d, f) {

      jQuery(document).on(a, b, function(e) {
        dataLayer.push({
          "event": 'event',
          "event_category": c,
          "event_action": d,
          "event_label": f
        });
      });

    }
    myFunction('mousedown', '#top_nav_link_331', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3');
  })()
</script>
```

*(I put the explanation here below 'cause I am having a format issue).*

Your problem Could be generated for many reasons. Supposing that you have GTM correctly installed on your website, here you have some ideas:

1. Your trigger could be wrong: try with DOM - All trigger.
   With your GTM console, when you are on preview mode, Test if your Custom HTML was fired or not.
2. Try to use the [IIFE](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/https-medium-com-javascript-in-plain-english-stop-feeling-iffy-about-using-an-iife-7b0292aba174) javascript functions when you create your tags (code above)